# How to track the details of glimpse with out showing the glimpse UI in a ASP.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, glimpse

I am trying to use glimpse.core and glimpse.aspnet in an ASP.NET application, but i don't want to display the glimpse UI, instead i want to track the details and need to save in a datastore. Is it possible?

Comment: I think [this question (and answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991943/how-do-i-enabled-in-a-read-only-capacity-in-glimpse/) will provide you all the information you need

Comment: @cgijbels thanks for the support.. I need to look in to it in detail..